# Room database error

Tags: java, android

**this my Code**

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
```

public final class Task {
    private static final String TAG = "Task";

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "entryId")
private final String mId;

@Nullable
@ColumnInfo(name = "title")
private final String mTitle;

@Nullable
@ColumnInfo(name = "description")
private final String mDescription;

@ColumnInfo(name = "completed")
private final boolean mCompleted;

public Task(@NonNull String Id, @Nullable String Title, @Nullable String Description, boolean Completed) {
    mId = Id;
    mTitle = Title;
    mDescription = Description;
    mCompleted = Completed;
}

/**
 * 这个构造函数用来创建正在执行的任务
 * 新建立的任务不可能马上被完成，
 * 所以这里completed = false
 */
@Ignore
public Task(@Nullable String Title, @Nullable String Description) {
    this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), Title, Description, false);
}

/**
 * 如果任务已经有了id，那么就创建一个正在执行的任务
 * 新建立的任务不可能马上被完成，
 * 所以这里completed = false
 */
@Ignore
public Task(@NonNull String Id, @Nullable String Title, @Nullable String Description) {
    this(Id, Title, Description, false);
}

/**
 * 使用这个构造函数创建一个已完成的任务
 */
@Ignore
public Task(@Nullable String Title, @Nullable String Description, boolean Completed) {
    this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), Title, Description, Completed);
}

@Nullable
public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}

@NonNull
public String getId() {
    return mId;
}

@Nullable
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}
```

**but i got a error,PLEASE HELP ME , this is google MVP sample**
**github:**https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/

AND THIS IS MY ERROR:

> Error:(16, 14) error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
>   Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
>   Task(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) : [Id : null, Title : null, Description : null, Completed : null]

**I'M THE NEW ONE, PLEASE HELP ME,THANK U VERY MUCH !!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove final from your class

```
public class Task
```

and implement an empty constructor

```
public Task(){}
```

and dont forget about your setters , you can aim your mouse at your class name and then alt + fn + insert and this will pop up and click setters, select all your variables and do the setters too as you did your getters

[image]

for example, one of my variables is pago, so a setter for pago that is an String will be like this

```
public void setPago(String pago) {
        this.pago = pago;
    }
```

this is one of my classes for demonstration...